# Issue with subscriber launch

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working through tutorials and am having issues with launching my subscriber launch file.

I have created a launch file named odom_subscriber.launch and have the following text in the launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="read_odometry" type="odom_subscriber.py" name="odom_sub_node" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

I have created my python file named odom_subscriber.py and have the following text in it:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python
    
    import rospy
    
    from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
    
    def callback(msg): 
    
      print msg 
        
    rospy.init_node('odom_sub_node')

sub = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, callback)

rospy.spin()
```

However, when I try to launch the launch file I get an error. I know I am not subscribing to anything just yet but I wanted to test it to see if all was good at this stage.

To launch the file I used the command:

```
roslaunch odom_subscriber.launch
```

I then get the error:

```
[odom_subscriber.launch] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359829/issue-with-subscriber-launch/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on 2020-08-19**:
I actually had this in my notes that I had taken and never spotted that I had to add the package also, how silly of me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: as corrected by @gvdhoorn

The syntax for running a launchfile is

```
roslaunch <package_name> <launchfile_name>
```

OR

```
roslaunch /path/to/file.launch
```

So in your case it would be sth like this:

`roslaunch your_package odom_subscriber.launch` or `roslaunch /path/to/odom_subscriber.launch`

See the [roslaunch wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch#Overview)

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2020-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-19**:
It could be this helped the OP, but for completeness: `roslaunch` does support launching `.launch` files not hosted by packages. So you could actually `roslaunch /path/to/my.launch`.